# WordPress Custom Post Type -show only certain type of taxonomy

Tags: php, wordpress

I am looking to show specific dishes that belong to specific menu.

- I've created a "dishes" custom post.
- I've created a custom "menu" taxonomy, with 3 types of menus ('premium', 'children', 'concept')

How do I create conditional syntax in the loop to search for that menu type and loop those posts that belong to that menu type?

### custom post

```
function custom_post_type_food_dish()
{
    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x('Dishes', 'Post Type General Name', 'text_domain'),
        'singular_name' => _x('Dish', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'text_domain'),
        'menu_name' => __('Dishes', 'text_domain'),
        'name_admin_bar' => __('Dish', 'text_domain'),
        'archives' => __('Item Archives', 'text_domain'),
        'attributes' => __('Item Attributes', 'text_domain'),
        'parent_item_colon' => __('Parent Item:', 'text_domain'),
        'all_items' => __('All Items', 'text_domain'),
        'add_new_item' => __('Add New Item', 'text_domain'),
        'add_new' => __('Add New', 'text_domain'),
        'new_item' => __('New Item', 'text_domain'),
        'edit_item' => __('Edit Item', 'text_domain'),
        'update_item' => __('Update Item', 'text_domain'),
        'view_item' => __('View Item', 'text_domain'),
        'view_items' => __('View Items', 'text_domain'),
        'search_items' => __('Search Item', 'text_domain'),
        'not_found' => __('Not found', 'text_domain'),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __('Not found in Trash', 'text_domain'),
        'featured_image' => __('Featured Image', 'text_domain'),
        'set_featured_image' => __('Set featured image', 'text_domain'),
        'remove_featured_image' => __('Remove featured image', 'text_domain'),
        'use_featured_image' => __('Use as featured image', 'text_domain'),
        'insert_into_item' => __('Insert into item', 'text_domain'),
        'uploaded_to_this_item' => __('Uploaded to this item', 'text_domain'),
        'items_list' => __('Items list', 'text_domain'),
        'items_list_navigation' => __('Items list navigation', 'text_domain'),
        'filter_items_list' => __('Filter items list', 'text_domain'),
    );
    $args = array(
        'label' => __('Dish', 'text_domain'),
        'description' => __('food_dish is the dishes that go into the menu', 'text_domain'),
        'labels' => $labels,
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'thumbnail', 'comments', 'post-formats',),
        //'taxonomies'            => array( 'category', 'post_tag' ),
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'show_in_admin_bar' => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'can_export' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'page',
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-image-filter',
    );
    register_post_type('food_dish', $args);

}
add_action('init', 'custom_post_type_food_dish', 0);
```

### custom taxonomy

```
function add_custom_taxonomies()
{
    // Add new "Menus" taxonomy to Posts
    register_taxonomy('menu', 'food_dish', array(
        // Hierarchical taxonomy (like categories)
        'hierarchical' => true,
        // This array of options controls the labels displayed in the WordPress Admin UI
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => _x('Menus', 'taxonomy general name'),
            'singular_name' => _x('Menu', 'taxonomy singular name'),
            'search_items' => __('Search Menus'),
            'all_items' => __('All Menus'),
            'parent_item' => __('Parent Menu'),
            'parent_item_colon' => __('Parent Menu:'),
            'edit_item' => __('Edit Menu'),
            'update_item' => __('Update Menu'),
            'add_new_item' => __('Add New Menu'),
            'new_item_name' => __('New Menu Name'),
            'menu_name' => __('Menus'),
        ),
        // Control the slugs used for this taxonomy
        'rewrite' => array(
            'slug' => 'menus', // This controls the base slug that will display before each term
            'with_front' => false, // Don't display the category base before "/locations/"
            'hierarchical' => true, // This will allow URL's like "/locations/boston/cambridge/"
        ),
    ));
}

add_action('init', 'add_custom_taxonomies', 0);
```

the HTML/PHP part in the template:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
                <?php
                $args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'food_dish',
                    'taxonomy_name' => 'menu'
                );
                $loop = new WP_Query($args);
                while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
                    //prePrint($loop);
                    if ( in_category( 'premium' ) ) {
                        ?>
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <?php the_post_thumbnail('medium', array('class' => 'img-responsive')); ?>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <p><?php the_excerpt() ?></p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                        <?php
                    }
                endwhile; ?>
            </div>
```